# Bahasa Melayu in iOS

Tags: ios, localization

I have an App whose target audience is based in Malaysia and can read and type in Malaysian Language. I have Localizable.strings file in Malaysian language.

There is an option in iOS for "Bahasa Melayu" in Language selection in Settings.app

I want to know which language should I select in Xcode so that my the device chooses the correct Localizable.strings file.

Any other details I should provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the abbreviation `ms.lproj` for the folder. I heard, all indonesian countries learn bahasa at school and I created also a folder with the same files inside a folder called `id.lproj`. Maybe you can tell me, if it's right that most people in Indonesia talk bahasa like a basic language.

The folders should look like this

[image]

If you insert the localization folder into your project it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was doing. I just chose Malay language in Xcode and Bahasa Melayu on iOS.
I believe it was some issue with my Xcode. After sometime it started working without any change.

Comment: To others coming here, make sure that your ms.lproj folder is added to your xCode project and the target app. It won't work if it isn't added to the project and the target.

Comment: It's like every other recourse you add to a project, thats why I didn't mention it. And the two pictures I included in my post show the folder inside the project's workspace and the localized files inside `xCode`. And every time you add files to your project, `xCode` asks if you want to add it or make a reference, in both cases the files are connected to your project ;)